# MouseEvent Listener not working with SimpleButton AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So I had to rewrite a project I am working on to not use the Starling framework and by extension Feathers, and now I am trying to get buttons working. My code currently is

```
    package  
{
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.SimpleButton;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
/**
 * ...
 * @author Fluzzarn
 */
public class StartScreen extends Screen 
{

    public var startGameButton:SimpleButton;
    public var optionsButton:SimpleButton;

    [Embed (source = "assets\\playGameButtonUp.png")]
    private var playButtonUp:Class
    [Embed (source = "assets\\playGameButtonDown.png")]
    private var playButtonDown:Class

    [Embed (source = "assets\\titleScreen.png")]
    private var backGround:Class;

    public function StartScreen() 
    {
        mouseChildren = true;
        super();
        startGameButton = new SimpleButton(new playButtonUp(), new playButtonDown());

        addChild(new backGround());
        addChild(startGameButton);
        startGameButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goToGame);
        trace(startGameButton.getBounds(stage));
    }

    private function goToGame(e:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        trace("Mouse Clicked");
        Main(parent).goToGame();
    }


}
```

}

The code works as intended if I just have the whole StartScreen object have the MouseEvent Listener, but when I add the listener to the button itself, it never triggers. It is probably something stupid, but my google-fu isn't working for me right now.

EDIT: Screen is just a base class that I have each of the screens in my game extend from, e.g. GameScreen, StartScreen, OptionScreen are all classes in my project

Comment: Why you are extending `Screen`?

Comment: Screen is just a base class that other classes extend to in order to switch between in Main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide the button with hitTestState - it's inactive. You gave him only up and hover states.

`startGameButton = new SimpleButton(new playButtonUp(), new playButtonDown(), new playButtonDown(), new playButtonDown());`